# Intent pass data not successful

Tags: java, android

I'm making a score list for a game, I had used the following code to pass the scoretime to ScoreActivity, but I don't know why it will only show the default number "1"

```
long timeSpent = System.currentTimeMillis() - initialTime;
timeSpent = (long) (timeSpent / 1000.0);
int apple = (int)timeSpent;
Intent scoreIntent = new Intent(GameActivity.this,ScoreActivity.class);
scoreIntent.putExtra("score",apple);

AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(GameActivity.this).create();
alertDialog.setTitle("Game Over!");
alertDialog.setMessage(" Total time " + String.valueOf(timeSpent));
alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE,"Exit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        Intent i =new Intent(getContext(), ScoreActivity.class);
        getContext().startActivity(i);
    }
```

In ScoreActivity

```
TextView myText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_score);
    myText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text444);
    Intent scoreIntent = getIntent();
    int rating = scoreIntent.getIntExtra("score", 1);
    String str = Integer.toString(rating);
    myText.setText(rating);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It shows the default value because you created an intent and put extras in it

```
Intent scoreIntent = new Intent(GameActivity.this,ScoreActivity.class);
scoreIntent.putExtra("score",apple);
```

that's right but when you started the activity you used another intent

```
Intent i =new Intent(getContext(), ScoreActivity.class);
getContext().startActivity(i);
```

and the value of `apple` isn't in the new intent `i` so a solution is to make your intent `scoreIntent` as `final` which you can access from your `onClick()` method like:

```
final Intent scoreIntent = new Intent(GameActivity.this,ScoreActivity.class);
scoreIntent.putExtra("score",apple);
```

and from `onClick()` you do this

```
getContext().startActivity(scoreIntent );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , when I run , there is no error but clashed

Answer (score 0):

You need pass your value here

```
Intent i =new Intent(getContext(),   ScoreActivity.class);
 i.putExtra("score",Apple);
getContext().startActivity(i);
```